# error: subprocess-exited-with-error | I have an error trying to install pysqlite3 with pip

Tags: python, sqlite, pip, python-wheel

I've been trying to install pysqlite via pip, but I get this error using the console command: `pip install pysqlite3`:

```
Collecting pysqlite3
  Using cached pysqlite3-0.5.0.tar.gz (40 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: pysqlite3
  Building wheel for pysqlite3 (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [18 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\pysqlite3
      copying pysqlite3\dbapi2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\pysqlite3
      copying pysqlite3\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\pysqlite3
      running build_ext
      Builds a C extension linking against libsqlite3 library
      building 'pysqlite3._sqlite3' extension
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\src
      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DMODULE_NAME=\"pysqlite3.dbapi2\" -I/usr/include "-IC:\Users\USUARIO\Documents\VSCode Projects\env\include" -IC:\Users\USUARIO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include -IC:\Users\USUARIO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt" /Tcsrc\blob.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\src\blob.obj
      blob.c
      C:\Users\USUARIO\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-repsnu9p\pysqlite3_2227e0dab76349b680a8874662134523\src\blob.h(4): fatal error C1083: No se puede abrir el archivo incluir: 'sqlite3.h': No such file or directory
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30133\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pysqlite3
  Running setup.py clean for pysqlite3
Failed to build pysqlite3
Installing collected packages: pysqlite3
  Running setup.py install for pysqlite3 ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Running setup.py install for pysqlite3 did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [20 lines of output]
      running install
      C:\Users\USUARIO\Documents\VSCode Projects\env\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
        warnings.warn(
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\pysqlite3
      copying pysqlite3\dbapi2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\pysqlite3
      copying pysqlite3\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\pysqlite3
      running build_ext
      Builds a C extension linking against libsqlite3 library
      building 'pysqlite3._sqlite3' extension
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\src
      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DMODULE_NAME=\"pysqlite3.dbapi2\" -I/usr/include "-IC:\Users\USUARIO\Documents\VSCode Projects\env\include" -IC:\Users\USUARIO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include -IC:\Users\USUARIO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt" /Tcsrc\blob.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\src\blob.obj
      blob.c
      C:\Users\USUARIO\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-repsnu9p\pysqlite3_2227e0dab76349b680a8874662134523\src\blob.h(4): fatal error C1083: No se puede abrir el archivo incluir: 'sqlite3.h': No such file or directory
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30133\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> pysqlite3

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

I need to implement pysqlite3 in python, but there seem to be various bugs which I don't understand. I also tried to install everything in a virtual environment (virtualenv) because I thought it might be an incompatibility of one of the packages I already have (like Flask, numpy, ect), but I keep getting the same error.

I also tried to install some specific version of pysqlite3 using `pip install pysqlite3=={version}`, but none of this has worked, the error remains the same.

I have tried updating pip, wheel and setuptools, but the error persists. Does anyone know how to fix it and be able to install pysqlite3?

Comment: You appear to be missing development headers for libsqlite3. Do you really need `pysqlite3` ? Could you not just use the built in [`sqlite3`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html) module ?